# What is the Hindu view of blasphemy?

Tags: sin

> blasphemy :
> the action or offence of speaking sacrilegiously about God or sacred things; profane talk.

Is blasphemy sin in Hinduism.

Comment: The Ten Naam-Apradha, due to lack of knowledge! But no such thing as Blasphemy!!       https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=III8vwGAbaY